# How to see which posts of mine have been deleted?

Tags: support

Today, I saw -50rep added to my reputation in my Movies.SE account, as a result of deletion of a user. So definitely one or more answers to his question(s) was/were deleted. So is there a way to see the deleted posts?

Comment: Only if you have more than 10k reputation.

Comment: @Linuxios, That site is still in beta and I have 5K+ rep there therefore access to all mod tools.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An entry in your reputation history that says:

> -50 User was removed

[image]

does not mean you lost 50 points because an answer of your was deleted.

An entry liike this mean an entire user was removed and as such, all of their votes were invalidated.  This specific user upvoted 5 of your answers or 10 of your questions, or some combination of both, so you lost that rep when they were removed.

Had an answer of yours been deleted (due to a post being removed), you would have seen an entry listing the specific post name (with an unclickable link)

Answer (score 3):

You can find posts of yours that have been recently deleted on your "recently deleted answers" and "recently deleted questions" pages.

You can find these by going to the "question" and "answer" tabs of your profile, and looking for the links at the bottom of the page.

> [image]

> [image]

If it was not deleted recently, then there is no easy way for an ordinary user to find it.

If you have "10k/access to mod tools", you may be able to find it under "Recently Deleted" in the in the "Delete" tab of `/tools` if there haven't been many other recent deletions.

Comment: I found nothing there. But the user was removed just 31mins ago :-O

Comment: @Mistu4u Hmm, weird. It's possible that it's cached and it will appear eventually. Since you mentioned that you have access to `/tools`, take a look in the "delete" tab there in the meanwhile.

Comment: Nah, found nothing in that tools too!! Looks like I gotta contact with the diamond mods there.

Comment: Ah! Looks like psubee2003 is correct here. Anyway thank you for your help :-)

Answer (score 2):

Users with the [Access To Moderator Tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) privilege (10k rep on graduated sites) can see their deleted posts by [searching `deleted:yes`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=deleted%3Ayes) on the site in question.

Note this shows only your own deleted posts.